# How clear messages queue generated from drupal_set_message in popups api ajax in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

How to clear messages queue generated from drupal set message when popups api ajax are open in Drupal?

Comment: You have 5 questions with good answers that you have not yet accepted. Please accept those answers and people will be far more inclined to help you

Answer (score 15):

Drupal 5-8: running [drupal_get_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/6) will clear the messages.

In 8.5.x there is a new [Messenger](https://www.drupal.org/node/2774931) service you can use. The `drupal_get_messages()` function will be deprecated.

Clearing all messages using the Messenger service:

`$messages = \Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();`

Comment: So weird as this old d6 solution would work on d8 as well. This is not working on d7.

Comment: It still works in D7. Make sure you aren't setting new messages after trying to clear the old ones.  Looking at the function on the api page, it works exactly the same in all version.

Comment: This works but one issue is it does not work on IE. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal 7:**

The messages are in $_SESSION if you want to clear for example the "status"-Messages you can do it like that:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['messages']['status'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['messages']['status']);
}
```

Comment: Actually this worked for me when ` \Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();` worked on all browser except IE. I had to add `unset($_SESSION['messages']`